# build android project from command line with different urls/ Environment

Tags: android, maven, build

I want to build the android project from command line. Usually, I build the project for two environments(merchant and production) and I want to do that for Merchant and Production URL automatically from command line, without me specifying in the project manually everytime. For example Say, Build a project for Production environment or say, build a project for merchant environment by specifying the environment in command itself. Can it be done? Please help.

Comment: Where do you actually store the URL value, in java source or xml resource?

Comment: We store the URL value in Strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ant, you can customize your project by copying a template resource file or a template java file that will be generated before running the release target of the standard android Ant file.

The generated files should be ignored to version control.

Here is a sample ANT target that should be called before building the application with ant release. It generates one java file and one resource file:

```
<target name="updateMyConfiguration"">
    <copy file="./MyTemplateConfiguration.java"
        tofile="./src/com/mycompany/android/myapp/MyCodeConfiguration.java"
        overwrite="true">
    </copy>
    <replace file="./src/com/mycompany/android/myapp/MyCodeConfiguration.java">
        <replacefilter token="token_my_boolean"
            value="${code.configuration.my_boolean}" />
        <replacefilter token="token_my_integer"
            value="${code.configuration.my_integer}" />
        <replacefilter token="token_my_string"
            value="${code.configuration.my_string}" />
    </replace>
    <copy file="./MyTemplateRes.xml"
        tofile="./res/values/MyResConfiguration.xml"
        overwrite="true">
    </copy>
    <replace file="./res/values/MyResConfiguration.xml">
        <replacefilter token="token_my_string"
            value="${res.configuration.my_string}" />
        <replacefilter token="token_my_integer"
            value="${res_configuration.my_integer}" />
    </replace>
</target>
```

```
package com.mycompany.android.myapp;

public final class MyCodeConfiguration
{
    static final boolean my_boolean = token_my_boolean;
    static final String my_string = "token_my_string";
    static final int my_integer = token_my_integer;
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <add-resource type="string" name="my_string"/>
    <string name="my_string">token_my_string</string>
    <add-resource type="integer" name="my_integer"/>
    <integer name="my_integer">token_my_integer</integer>
</resources>
```

Then you just need to run Ant this way:

```
ant updateMyConfiguration -Dres.configuration.string=MyCustomBuildString -Dcode.configuration.my_integer=1234
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build your project with Maven, Ant and Gradle. All of them will do what you want.
I use Maven therefore I'll focus on Maven configuration. It might be a complex task if you don't know how Maven works.

### Configure Maven

First prerequisites described here:
https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted

Configure your project to build with android maven plugin:
https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

Sample configuration for Eclipse:
https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/QuickStartForEclipseProject

You can also generate sample project with the command below:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.8 \
  -DgroupId=com.myproject \
  -DartifactId=my-android-application
```

### Create profile

Second step is create build profiles for production.

**IMPORTANT:** the following profile snippet bases works pom.xml generated with command `mvn archetype:generate` command above.

The profile listed below replaces string in file located in res/values/strings.xml

form:

```
<string name="hello">Whatever text</string>
```

to:

```
 <string name="hello">productionURL</string>
```

The profile (include it in pom.xml above `</project>`):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>replace</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/res/values/strings.xml</file>
                        <regex>true</regex>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token><![CDATA[(<string name="hello">)(.+)(</string>)]]></token>
                                <value><![CDATA[$1productionURL$3]]></value>
                            </replacement>         
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                        </sign>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

It uses https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/ to replace string.

For Merchant just copy-paste `<profile>` listed above, change `<id>production</id>` to `<id>merchant</id>` and in `<value>` update url.

### Build

```
mvn install -Pproduction
```

or

```
mvn install -Pmerchant
```

Comment: Note that android-maven-plugin support resource filtering natively, you don't need rely on extra maven-replacer-plugin to substitute the value, check out answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867148/maven-and-android-slightly-different-builds-for-different-environments/13868351#13868351) to see a sample configuration.

Comment: @yorkw---I am getting the following error while building..Can you please help me out.    [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Error resolving version for plugin 'c
om.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin' from the repos
itories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\user\.m2\repository), central (http:
//repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [

Comment: @Raghav, if you use pawelzieba's sample configuration, add `<version>3.3.2</version>` in android-maven-plugin section. it is usually defined in the parent pom.xml (reason why it is not in pawelzieba's sample configuration).

Comment: @Raghav I added notice to profile section. It was tested with pom.xml generated with the command listed in Configure Maven.
To yorkw, I haven't known the feature in android-maven-plugin, thanks! It looks simple, but I think it has small drawbacks - it seems to work only with maven and it creates special filtered folders which is little dirty.

Comment: The only good pont I see to use maven-replacer-plugin is it let you filter specific subfolder/files, whereas if using android-maven-plugin, it is required to filter the whole res/ or assets/ folder even though you just need to filter a single file.

Comment: @yorkw I honestly disagree. How does look import project to IDE. Do they correctly recognize template files in separated folders?

Comment: @pawelzieba, for this particular case i.e. strings.xml, ADT is smarter enough to handle the `${xxx}` pattern.