# Creating Config Files in Maven

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

In the project I am working on at the moment we have 2 servers. Staging and production.

We are using maven to build the project. When a new version is pushed to github jenkins then builds a new version and pushes it to hockey app, where are testers can access it.

What we would like to do it have jenkins pass in different parameters dependent on the branch which then make a config file for the app.

We want to do this for the server url. So when I push a version to staging it makes the config file and the app reads the server url from there.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: not sure I understand... but you only have one jenkins job for both servers ? (and if it's the case why don't you create a jenkins job per branch i.e. per target server)

Comment: the idea is to have 2 branches and 1 jenkins job for each branch

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867148/maven-and-android-slightly-different-builds-for-different-environments) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Maven [resource filtering](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering.html) and [build profile](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html) concepts in the Maven By Example book by Sonatype.

Furthermore, you will probably want to have separate jobs for these profiles in Jenkins.