# Using Maven to build application for different environments (dev, staging, prod)

Tags: android, maven

Suppose I have the following properties declared in my `pom.xml` file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    // ....

    <properties>
        <dev.url>http://dev.mysite.com</dev.url>
        <staging.url>http://staging.mysite.com</staging.url>
        <prod.url>http://prod.mysite.com</prod.url>
    </properties>

</project>
```

What I would like to do, is to have different run configurations, and depending of some flag I set, to read the corresponding property. For example when building for production, to read at runtime the `prod.url` property, when building for staging, to read the `staging.url` property.

Comment: that's not the proper place to put properties. put them in android resources.

Comment: you can make a script that copy your pom.xml file in the assets folder each time you build the project.And then you are able to parse it

Comment: @njzk2 The idea is that this property will be different for different environments (build, production, staging). Ideally, I would have different run configurations, that when launched, will read the corresponding property. If I put them in Android resources, is there  a way I could pass a flag from the run configuration so that the appropriate resource to be selected at run time (without the need to manually edit the code and change the environment)?

Comment: I am not sure whether the pom.xml even is packaged to the .apk file? I suppose you should have various run configurations defined in IDE and set parameters there. But I am not sure if it will work

Comment: @AndyRes, see if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867148/maven-and-android-slightly-different-builds-for-different-environments/13868351#13868351) helps. To sum up, define your properties in pom.xml and a placeholder in strings.xml, and use resource filtering substitute the placeholder in strings.xml at project build tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:
The idea was to store all the properties in separate resource files. Then, using [maven resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) copy the corresponding property file into `values/environment.xml`

In your project root directory create following directory structure:

```
environment/dev/environment.xml
environment/prod/environment.xml
```

Then fill the content of the resource files with appropriate values.

**/dev/environment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://dev.mysite.com</string>
</resources>
```

**/prod/environment.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://prod.mysite.com</string>
</resources>
```

Add the maven resource plugin to `pom.xml` by specifying the phase where this action should be executed, the resources to copy, and the output directory:

```
//...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>copy-string-resources</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>environment/${environment}/</directory>
                            <includes>
                               <include>environment.xml</include>
                               <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/res/values/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
```

From this point you could create 2 run configurations:

```
mvn validate -Denvironment=dev
mvn validate -Denvironment=prod
```

that will do nothing but copy the appropriate resources from `evironment/${environment}/environment.xml`, into `values/environment.xml`

Depending of run configuration, `${environment}` will be equal with `dev` or `prod`.

You can find more info on [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/using-maven-in-android-to-build-for-different-environments-dev-staging-prod-etc/) page.