# How to update androidManifest uses-permissions before renameManifestPackage with maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I need to build the same application 5 times with 5 packages. 
I'm using , it's working, all the apps can be on one phone.

But I need to use C2D_MESSAGE permission 
I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803088/how-do-i-change-my-androidmanifest-as-its-being-packaged-by-maven?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
<uses-permission android:name="${xxx.package}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

It's not working as the androidManifest is moved before the renameManifestPackage action.
My app's not compiling, because the filtered manifest is use, and renameManifestPackage work for the other manifest.

Is there any way to modify androidManifest before renameManifestPackage, to set uses-permission ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location of the AndroidManifest.xml used the android-maven-plugin with this parameter : [`<androidManifestFile>`](http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/apk-mojo.html#androidManifestFile)

The default value is `${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml` , so if you change it so that it takes the filtered AndroidManifest.xml (somewhere under your target directory, it's difficult to say precisely where it will be without your pom.xml) instead of the one at project root: it will probably solve your problem.

Comment: I already done this, but the renameManifestPackage didn't work, the app couldn't compile because of a package name problem.