# Update the app name and logo based on the maven android build profile

Tags: java, android, maven, android-manifest

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="20411" android:versionName="2.4.11-SNAPSHOT" package="com.customcompany">

    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="com.customcompany.percustomssion.AUTHENTICATE_USER"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-percustomssion android:name="com.customcompany.percustomssion.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY"/>


    <!--<uses-percustomssion android:name="android.percustomssion.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>

    <percustomssion android:description="@string/percustomssion_launchActivity_description" android:label="@string/percustomssion_launchActivity_label" android:name="com.customcompany.percustomssion.LAUNCH_ACTIVITY" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <percustomssion android:description="@string/percustomssion_authenticateUser_description" android:label="@string/percustomssion_authenticateUser_label" android:name="com.customcompany.percustomssion.AUTHENTICATE_USER" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>-->

    <uses-sdk android:customnSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"  android:largeHeap="true" android:logo="@drawable/actionbarlogo" android:name="com.customcompany.application.CustomApplication" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.customcompany.activities.ExternalLaunchActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.activities.CustomAirlineActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.payment.CardPaymentActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.payment.CashPaymentActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.chooseflight.FlightDataActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.login.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.forms.FormEntryActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.customcompany.manual.reader.pdfreader.PDFReaderAct" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation"  android:name="com.customcompany.manual.reader.pdfreader.AndroidListViewActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  android:name="com.customcompany.manual.CustomManualActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.customcompany.manual.reader.genericreader.GenericReader" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.customcompany.service.ControlledReplicationService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.couchbase.android.CouchbaseService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.customcompany.service.LocalCouchService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.customcompany.ifs.discovery.InflightSyncService"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.customcompany.manual.reader.htmlreader.HTMLReader" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name="com.customcompany.payment.PreOrderActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomAirline.ActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Pom file

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>${proguard.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <release>true</release>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                    </sign>
                    <zipalign>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                        <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apk
                        </inputApk>
                        <outputApk>
                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-signed-aligned.apk
                        </outputApk>
                    </zipalign>
                    <manifest>
                        <debuggable>false</debuggable>
                        <!-- note: below is set to false for testing. Feel free to use auto-increment
                            if you are sure about using auto-increment -->
                        <versionCodeAutoIncrement>false</versionCodeAutoIncrement>
                    </manifest>
                    <proguard>
                        <!-- Set the skip to false when making a proguard release -->
                        <skip>true</skip>
                        <config>${proguard.config}</config>
                        <jvmArguments>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xms512m</jvmArgument>
                            <jvmArgument>-Xmx1024m</jvmArgument>
                        </jvmArguments>
                    </proguard>
                    <manifestApplicationLabel>CrewApp-CD</manifestApplicationLabel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I would like to control the name of the app and logo for it based on the maven profile  I select to build the Android project. Is this a supported feature, if so , how do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the android-maven plugin (at least in version 3.80). The following is a blueprint for the profile in the pom:

```
<profile>
        <id>yourProfile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <manifestApplicationLabel>yourLabel</manifestApplicationLabel>
                        <manifestApplicationIcon>yourIcon</manifestApplicationIcon>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

For other parameters see the maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please share the documentation for this project.Apologies I could not find one for this plusin. I would like to know other options suppported

Comment: This this not work since the app name is specified under `application` tag.I think it works for all the properties under manifest tag. I am updating my pom and manifest file.

Comment: It was working for me. Try getting rid of `android:label` in the `<activity>` and you don't need `${manifestApplicationLabel}` in the `<application>` tag. Frankly I don't know if the order of `<execution>` and `<configuration>` is important, but maybe you should change it. And I see that you have the `manifest-update` goal twice in your pom.

Comment: Will try that and let you know

Comment: I removed the label property from the manifest and changed the order in the pm and removed the duplicate update. But when the app is built, the app namer is the activityName now. Have updated with the latst Manifest and pom

Comment: Hmm strange. I will try your configuration on a test project and get back to you

Comment: I got the issue. I was not defining the plugin under the profile I was using. I will try this now and get back to you